# How to choose a good grinder for a gaggia espresso machine?

Tags: espresso

I am using a Gaggia classic espresso machine and am looking for a grinder that will work well in combination with it.

What are the characteristics I need to keep in mind when selecting a grinder? What is better? A conical burr or a flat burr grinder? What gives the better grind?

At the moment, I have a crupps, but it has very coarse grinding steps.

Answer (score 1):

For espresso, you should use a *stepless* grinder (meaning, instead of a small number of grind sizes, you can fine tune the dial continuously) with *conical burs* (which are a certain shape of grinding wheels that provide consistency and precision). A standard recommendation is the Baratza Sette. The Reddit community [/r/coffee](https://www.reddit.com/r/Coffee/wiki/gear_guide_grinders#wiki_mid_range) provides more guidelines on shopping for coffee grinders.